# 3rd party libraries (closed source)

Tags: go, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Is there a way that you can build a binary file (shared or static library) in go language with bunch of source files and distribute it along with it's interfaces.

It's not to be distributed as an executable but a linkable static or shared library with interfaces at compile or run time. (Just like in C you distribute `.a` or `.so` file along with header files)

Unlike open source github based libraries out there it's a closed source project that i'm trying to port for Go.

Comment: The result of building a normal go program is a single binary, which you can distribute in accordance with whatever license the software carries (I''m not sure what "along with it's interfaces" is supposed to mean). What exactly is the question?

Comment: I edited, it's not to be built as executable, it has to be a linkable library at compile time or run time.

Comment: along with interfaces i mean just like in C, you distribute .a or .so file along with header files

Comment: You could build a C library with [`-buildmode`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_modes), if you can accept only a C interface.

Comment: These are called binary-only packages, and support for them is being dropped in Go 1.13: [cmd/go: drop support for binary-only packages](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28152)

Comment: is there a documentation page for binary only packages, I'm still curious how it was done

Comment: @Developer: they are still covered in the official docs: https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible . You can build your code as a static library and link it in runtime with this command :

```
go build -buildmode=plugin
```

You can use built plugin like this :

A Symbol is a pointer to a variable or function.

For example, a plugin defined as

```
package main

import "fmt"

var V int

func F() { fmt.Printf("Hello, number %d\n", V) }
```

may be loaded with the Open function and then the exported package symbols V and F can be accessed

```
p, err := plugin.Open("plugin_name.so")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
v, err := p.Lookup("V")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
f, err := p.Lookup("F")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
*v.(*int) = 7
f.(func())() // prints "Hello, number 7"


type Symbol interface{}
```

Check out built in support for [Plugin](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/) in go for more info

Comment: Thanks Mostafa, can you please also mention how to do a compile time plugin? .a file so to speak

Comment: with plugin mode compilation you will have a .so library

Comment: with my understanding .so is run time linking and it's fine i needed that too, what about compile time library? how to build that

Comment: you can't have that

Comment: Plugins aren't as simple as setting the `buildmode`. The application and plugin have to be build specifically to use the stdlib plugin system. And it's only supported on Linux.

Comment: Mostafa, can you elaborate on the command line, like how to specify multiple files for the build

Comment: your library package name should be main. Build the static library like normal program . Enter into the plugin folder that contains one or multiple .go files and run : go build -buildmode=plugin -o mylib.so

Comment: This is also a good tutorial to check out : https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/writing-modular-go-programs-with-plugins-ec46381ee1a9

Comment: @MostafaSolati I followed the tutorial, i'm trying to add two files (space separated) in one `so`, `go build -buildmode=plugin -o bin/langs.so src/test/eng/greeter.go src/test/chi/greeter.go` but no success, so it has to be one and only one file?

Comment: I did appended the language suffix from each language file to avoid any conflicts.